# Integer column contains String data

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have an Android application which contains a SQLite Database. One of the fields in a table is of type Integer but i've for some reason been able to save strings to it all this time. I didn't realise I was doing so until recently.

The column is called `favourited`, of type `integer` and i'm able to save strings that look like dates. Yes, a very strange implementation on my part, but please tell me if you know why it hasn't thrown an exception or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> SQLite uses a more general dynamic type system. In SQLite, the datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its container. The dynamic type system of SQLite is backwards compatible with the more common static type systems of other database engines in the sense that SQL statements that work on statically typed databases should work the same way in SQLite. However, the dynamic typing in SQLite allows it to do things which are not possible in traditional rigidly typed databases.

and

> In order to maximize compatibility between SQLite and other database engines, SQLite supports the concept of "type affinity" on columns. The type affinity of a column is the recommended type for data stored in that column. The important idea here is that the type is recommended, not required. Any column can still store any type of data. It is just that some columns, given the choice, will prefer to use one storage class over another. The preferred storage class for a column is called its "affinity".

Answer (score 0):

Actually SQLite stores everything as String. Numbers are stored as "12345". So integer and other column types are more informative than usable.

Comment: This is not correct. Read more from the link provided by Henry in his answer.